# How to use ARM template for Vcore based Elastic Pool deployment?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-elasticpool

I am trying to use Azure ARM template (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-sql-elastic-pool-create/azuredeploy.json) to create SQL azure elastic pool, I am able use it and create eDTU based elastic pools, however I need to create Vcore based, Any leads on it?

Comment: Any update? Could it solve your issue?

Comment: Yeah, it works.. I did have few troubles related to location of the resource group I was using to create server and vcore based elastic pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the template as below, it works fine on my side.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "administratorLogin": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "administratorLoginPassword": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "serverName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "serverLocation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "elasticPoolName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "skuName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tier": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "poolLimit": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "poolSize": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "perDatabasePerformanceMin": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "perDatabasePerformanceMax": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "zoneRedundant": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": false
        },
        "licenseType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "allowAzureIps": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": true
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
            "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
                "version": "12.0"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2017-10-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/', parameters('elasticPoolName'))]",
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
                        "tier": "[parameters('tier')]",
                        "capacity": "[parameters('poolLimit')]"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "perDatabaseSettings": {
                            "minCapacity": "[parameters('perDatabasePerformanceMin')]",
                            "maxCapacity": "[parameters('perDatabasePerformanceMax')]"
                        },
                        "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('poolSize')]",
                        "zoneRedundant": "[parameters('zoneRedundant')]",
                        "licenseType": "[parameters('licenseType')]"
                    },
                    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools"
                },
                {
                    "condition": "[parameters('allowAzureIps')]",
                    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
                    "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                    "properties": {
                        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                    },
                    "type": "firewallrules"
                }
            ],
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My sample parameters:**

[image]

**Check result in the portal:**

[image]